# Javascript: How to hide a div which is dynamically created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a `div` dynamically using the following code:

```
$('#pageTabContent').append($('\
    <div class="tab-pane" id="'+user_id+'">\
        <div class="extras_area">\
            <div class="expand_heading">Header to be clicked</div>\
            <div class="expandable_content">this should be expanded.</div>\
        </div>\
    </div>'));
```

This is expanded within this HTML:

```
<div id="right_column">
    <ul id="pageTab" class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>
    <div id="pageTabContent" class="tab-content"></div>
</div>
```

I now want to expand the `.expandable_content` when I click the `.expand_heading`. To do this, I'm trying something like this in my javascript:

```
$("#right-column").on("load", ".expand_heading", hide);
$("#right-column").on("click", ".expand_heading", function(){
    $(this).next(".expandable_content").slideToggle(100);
});
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I don't know how to hide the `div` correctly when it is dynamically created. Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: @A.Wolff - No, that is always there in the html.

Comment: I hope that "right_column" and "right-column" difference is just here by mistake ? :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/t3WVs/

```
$('#pageTabContent').append($('\
    <div class="tab-pane" id="'+Math.random()+'">\
        <div class="extras_area">\
            <div class="expand_heading">Header to be clicked</div>\
            <div class="expandable_content">this should be expanded.</div>\
        </div>\
    </div>'));

//$(document).on("load", ".expand_heading", hide);
$(document).on("click", ".expand_heading", function(){
    $(this).next(".expandable_content").slideToggle(100);
});
// if needed default close expand
// $('.expand_heading').click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just use `display:none` rule:

```
$('#pageTabContent').append($('\
<div style="display:none;" class="tab-pane" id="'+user_id+'">\
    <div class="extras_area">\
        <div class="expand_heading">Header to be clicked</div>\
        <div class="expandable_content">this should be expanded.</div>\
    </div>\
</div>'));
```